# Multi-process safe sharedprefs

Tags: android, multiprocessing, sharedpreferences

Is it safe to use `SharedPreferences` if I have 2 processes in my app and I will create 2 separate preference files? I mean 1 file for main process and 2nd file for 2nd process. And the 2 processes wouldn't access other than their own file?
For creating separate files I would use:
`Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`, where name is name of the file.

Comment: Accessing the same sharedpreferences from multiple processes can cause issues.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `SharedPreferences` are not safe for use by multiple processes.

Comment: @CommonsWare And If I will use the technique above it is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you are careful and do not accidentally try using the same `SharedPreferences` on both processes, what you describe should be OK.

Personally, I would consider using some other form of file (e.g., JSON, SQLite), as I'm not certain what the advantage is of using `SharedPreferences` here.

Comment: Currently I am accesing shredprefs from main thread is it ok to use Sqlite this way?

Comment: @user221256: `SharedPreferences` are cached when you first access them. Ideally, that first read is done on a background thread. Subsequent accesses are fine from the main application thread. Disk I/O (files, SQLite, etc.) should be done on background threads, though you can cache the information yourself for use on the main application thread, if you wish.

Comment: Only read operarions are performed on cached data, editing is done async, right?

Comment: @user221256: On `SharedPreferences.Editor`, `apply()` is asynchronous. `commit()` is synchronous, for cases where you are already on a background thread and wish to update the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thank you very much I will see what I can come with. :)